# What framework should I use for a mobile app that notfies me when a webpage changes?

Tags: react-native

I have a very simple script that uses jQuery to set up an event listener to check if a DOM element was modified. When it is, it alerts the user  (and switches tabs).

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 
var gunga = document.querySelector("span[data-click-id='unanswered label']");
 
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', gunga, function() {
    alert("New question!");
});
 
async function initalSetup() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
    alert("Make sure you allow me to switch tabs!");
}
```

I'd like to port this to my phone, and I thought that React Native would be a good framework to use. Is this not the case, and if so would you explain why guide me in the right direction, perhaps with another framework?

Answer (score 0):

For this you should first consider whether the app should really run on android and ios.

#### YES

Now the question arises as to what experience you have as a developer.

1. Do you already know JavaScript and TypeScript?
2. Do you already have experience with ReactJS?

Then React Native is a very good choice. This also applies if you need further help and have to or want to save costs.

But even if you have decided to go with React Native, there are other things to consider.

Do you want to start with a first prototype as soon as possible? Then the choice could fall on EXPO to speed up the development. But be careful here. For example, Expo does not support all payment providers.

Which in turn can lead to the app not being able to be listed in the appstore.

#### NO

Consider which framework fulfills ALL the requirements you need.

I think that the best choice here is to choose the currently most popular framework. This ensures that support and additional employees can still be found in a few years.

If you already have basic knowledge of a framework, I would first "master" it before you go the way and learn a completely new one. The time you save with basic knowledge cancels out all arguments for another framework.